# Creating a calculator using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just starting out using ASP.Net and currently I'm trying to create a simple calculator just using MVC. I have my view layout but I have trouble calling the objects I want. If you know any good guides or helping out with my problem that would be great. For my results action, I am looking at one guide and it is throwing me off with what to do with it.
View:

```
    @using CalculatorApp.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CalcController")) { 
<div>
    <h2>@Html.Label("Enter first number") : @Html.TextBox("num1")</h2>
    <h2>@Html.Label("Enter second number") : @Html.TextBox("num2")</h2>
</div>
<div>   
    <h2>

        @Html.RadioButton("calkey", "0") +
           <br>
        @Html.RadioButton("calkey", "1") -
           <br>
        @Html.RadioButton("calkey", "2") *
           <br>
        @Html.RadioButton("calkey", "3") /
    </h2>            
</div>
    <input type="submit" name="Index" value="Index"/>
}
```

Model:

```
namespace CalculatorApp.Models
{
    public class Calculations : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Calculations/
        public int num1 { get; set; }
        public int num2 { get; set; }
        public int result { get; set; }

        public bool add { get; set; }
        public bool sub { get; set; }
        public bool mult { get; set; }
        public bool div  { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace CalculatorApp.Controllers
{
    public class CalcController : Controller
    {     
        public ActionResult Index(Calculations calc)
        {
            int selectedFunction = Convert.ToInt32(Request["calkey"]);

            switch (selectedFunction)
            {
                case 0:
                    calc.result = calc.num1 + calc.num2;
                    break;
                case 1:
                        calc.result = calc.num1 - calc.num2;
                        break;
                case 2:
                        calc.result = calc.num1 * calc.num2;
                        break;
                case 3:
                        if (calc.num2 > 0)
                        {
                            calc.result = calc.num1 / calc.num2;
                        }
                        break; 
            }
            return View(calc);
        }

        public ActionResult Result(Calculations calc)
        {

            return View(calc);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I want to solve is how do I make the calculations work when I press the submit button. I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Few problems I notice (1) Your `Calculations` POCO should not inherit from `Controller`. (2) Your `Index` action in `CalcController` should just return the view and `Result` action is where user inputs are going to get in and calculations performed and result returned.

Comment: I would recommend to narrow down your question because it looks more like a request for code-writing service (re: "I have no idea where to begin" - this raises the reasonable concern of where this code came from? If this is your code, then you probably should know how it works). Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few Problems I notice

1. At Your **View** You have to remove Controller at Html.BeginForm (put controller name (Calc) only)

   Change `Html.BeginForm("Index", "CalcController")` to `Html.BeginForm("Index", "Calc")`
2. At your **Model** you should not inherit controller

   Change `public class Calculations : Controller` to `public class Calculations`
3. At your **Controller**

   As you post your data at *Index* Method you can Remove *Result* method from controller. After that add new get method named 'Index' like

   `public ActionResult Index()
   {
       return View();
   }`

At last you must want to show your result at the view. so create a element at the Index View like `@Html.TextBox("result")`

**Update**

If you want to post data at Result Method

1. Replace Index to Result at `@Html.BeginForm`
2. Remove all code (parameter also) from Index Method (put return view() only) and paste those code at Result Method.